# Rx .NET: ToTask vs LastAsync vs RunAsync

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

Reactive Extensions has these three methods:

- `ToTask`: Returns a task that will receive the last value or the exception produced by the observable sequence.
- `LastAsync`: Returns the last element of an observable sequence
- `RunAsync`: Gets an awaiter that returns the last value of the observable sequence or throws an exception if the sequence is empty.

They sound very similar. How would I choose which one to use?

Comment: I would use `RunAsync`, because it seems to have more flexibility :)

Answer (score 1):

You should choose based on what you want to do with returning value, as these methods have different return types with different capabilities. If you only want to `await` last result you can use any of the methods above as they provide same behavior in this case. They all handle empty observable collections and exceptions when awaited.

Comment: So where lies the difference then?

Comment: The difference is in the behavior of these methods and in the returning types, which can be consumed differently.